# Windows 7 64 / Visual Studio 2008 / OpenCV2.1 error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xhex).."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, opencv

I'm building OpenCV2.1 from top of branch in 64 bit mode, when I link the libraries against my code (that works in 32 bit mode on XP), I get the dialog:

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002) Click OK to close the application"

When I start the application.  The event viewer is pointing at one of the OpenCV dll's & says it's a Side-by-Side error, but I'm definitely building OpenCV & my code as a 64 bit compile, and there are no errors during that process.  I've tried fiddling with the /MTd options & it doesn't help.  Some (almost) related questions have suggested installing the VS2008 redistributable package, but I'm building using vs2008 pro, that seems like madness?  Is it still necessary to install the package in my case?

Any help, including the cause of these side-by-side errors, would be appreciated.

James

Answer (score 1):

i had the same trouble when i just downloaded OpenCV-2.1.0-win32-vs2008.exe.

all you need is to rebuid OpenCV libs and dlls following instructions here
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2010_CMake.

CMake 2.8.2 is enough BTW.

Comment: I believe this is the same procedure I was using for the comment!  I built using VS not CMake though, will CMake libs link into VS projects?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an application of my own that uses the xerces C++ library. It did not work under Windows Vista/7 64 bits in debug mode but it works perfectly in Release mode.

The solution was to recompile the xerces C++ library in debug mode in my own machine. For some reason, the released binaries for VC++ 10 did not work well in 64 bits Vista/7

Comment: Please let me know if you discover what that reason is!